# how to add pic/icon beside app name

Tags: android

i want to add my app icon to the left of my app name like the one i marked in the picture.

i have tried some suggestion from here like 
adding android:logo in my manifest

making a link with @style

and some more that i already forgot

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and none of them work, can i ask some help regarding this?

[image]

Comment: try make custom `ActionBar` and inflate it

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity overide the  onCreateOptionsMenu method

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

      getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
```